# FormData vs submit when an input has different values

Tags: javascript, form-data

We have text inputs that contain a user-readable value and hold a different corresponding value for internal calculations. Example:

We set the attribute like this (in our use case 'b' changes with user input, but that's not relevant to the question):

```
 var input = document.getElementById('my-input')
 input.value = 'a'
 input.setAttribute('value', 'b')
```

The result is this HTML, an input field that displays 'a':

```
<input id='my-input' value='b' type='text' />
```

This is the result:

```
input.value === 'a' // displayed in the input field
input.getAttribute('value') === 'b' // stored in the "value" attribute
```

When I directly submit this form without adding any JavaScript, the server gets "b", corresponding to the **"value" attribute** of the input. When I submit it using the Javascript `new FormData(form)`, it submits "a".

**Is there documentation on how each of these two methods extract the value from the input?**

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML as well. How are you getting `3 Thousand` into the field?

Comment: Why did you tag this jQuery? My question is strictly about FormData vs. vanilla form submit, the jQuery is just to illustrate

Comment: JQuery's `attr()` method can often cause this kind of problem, so it could be relevant. You didn't say in your post that it was added just to illustrate. You need to show us the actual code you are working with.

Comment: I have removed the jQuery to make it clearer. You can achieve this by doing `input.value = 'a'; input.settAttribute('value', 'b')`

Answer (score 2):

- This `input.value` contains the live data within your `input` field.
- This `input.getAttribute('value')` returns the data you've used to declare your input and it's modified by `input.setAttribute` function.
- The `FormData`works with the live value `input.value`, so, your entered values will be submitted and not the data within your attribute `value`.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var input = document.getElementById('my-input')
  console.log(input.value); // This is what you've entered.
  console.log(input.getAttribute('value')); //This how was declared your input.

  var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
  console.log(fd.values()['next']());
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <p>Write something different and then click on button</p>
  <input name="myinput" id="my-input" value="Hello!"></input>
  <button id="btn">Click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know whether that means that normal HTTP form submit and javascript's new FormData(form) read the value in different ways?

Comment: @KWeiss answer updated.  As you can see, FormData will get the current entered value, therefore will get `input.value`

Comment: Thank you! Is there documentation for this, and for the difference from a normal form submit?

Comment: I recommend to read this: [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and use Google :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the understanding of the difference between HTML attributes and JavaScript Object properties.

When the browser parses the HTML, it constructs the Document Object Model as well. This is the "in memory" representation of the HTML elements as JavaScript Objects.

During that process of constructing the DOM, HTML attribute values become the **default** values of corresponding JavaScript Object properties. But this is just a copying of data - it's not a two-way data binding between attribute and property. If the property value is changed explicitly (which is the case in your example), the attribute value will not change. Attribute values are changed with `.setAttribute()`, while property values are read/set via the property name.

This means that the HTML can have a statically set attribute value, but the JavaScript object that represents it can have a different value for the property that corresponds to the attribute.

This is also why I initially tagged your question with JQuery, because the JQuery `.attr()` method extracts the value of the static HTML attribute and the `.prop()` method extracts the dynamic value of the JavaScript Object property.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('my-input');

// Both of the following will output "a" because the value was originally 
// gotten from the attribute and no changes to either have been made yet.
console.log(input.getAttribute("value"), input.value); // a, a

// Here, the value property is now being changed, so we will get two
// different results
input.value = 'b';
console.log(input.getAttribute("value"), input.value); // a, b

// Here, the attribute is being changed, but that won't affect 
// the object property that was previously set:
input.setAttribute('value', 'c');
console.log(input.getAttribute("value"), input.value); // c, b

var theForm = document.querySelector("form");
theForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  
  // Examine the form data:
  var formData = new FormData(theForm);
  for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
  }
  
  // Examine the element's data directly
  console.log("my-input,", input.value);
});
```

```html
<form method="GET" action="#">
<input id='my-input' value='a' name="my-input" type='text'>
<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know whether that means that normal HTTP form submit and javascript's `new FormData(form)` read the value in different ways?

Comment: @KWeiss I do not believe the key/value pairs are any different between the two techniques.

Comment: @KWeiss Please see my updated answer for a demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for this, but it does not answer my question. What I need is some form of documentation about FormData vs. ordinary form submit

Comment: @KWeiss I have already told you that there is no difference, but here is the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: I have not found anything in that documentation that mentions how the value is extracted from the input, did I miss it?

Comment: @KWeiss The reason you don't see anything explicitly stating what the differences are is because there are no differences. There is nothing pertaining to that to document. The form data is the current values of the form elements (the property values). See my updated answer that shows this.